# R - Identifying ranges of fixed width by value count

Tags: r, range, binning

Assume an ordered set of 100 binary values. Using a window size of 10, I would like to know the ranges (i.e., start and end position) of those windows that contain at least *x* "1s" (where *x*=3, for example).

```
> set.seed(123456789)
> full=rep(0,100)
> full[sample(1:100, 15)]=1
> split(full, ceiling(seq_along(full)/10))
$`1`
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

$`2`
 [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$`3`
 [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

$`4`
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

$`5`
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

$`6`
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$`7`
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1

$`8`
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

$`9`
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0

$`10`
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Here's what I am looking for:

```
> desired_function(full)
61-70
81-90
```

Comment: Please use `set.seed`

Comment: @akrun Adjusted as requested

Comment: but, your input is not the same as mine with the same seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to do a rolling apply function or (`rollsum`) with `width` 10, check if there are 3 1s (binary data), get the position of logical vector with `which`, convert it to buckets using `cut` and get the `unique` values of the bucket

```
library(zoo)
unique(cut(which(rollapply(full, 10, function(x) sum(x) == 3)), 
  breaks = c(-Inf, 11, 20, 31, 40, 51, 60), 
      labels = c('11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61-70')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reprex in base R:

```r
set.seed(123456789)

full <- rep(0,100)
full[sample(1:100, 15)] <- 1
my_list <- split(full, ceiling(seq_along(full)/10))
names(my_list) <- paste(10 * (as.numeric(names(my_list)) - 1) + 1, 
                        10 * (as.numeric(names(my_list)) - 1) + 10,
                        sep = " - ")
names(which(sapply(my_list, function(x) sum(x) == 3)))
#> [1] "21 - 30" "31 - 40"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>